# Don't understand the difference between Foo<T extends Foo> and Foo<T extends Foo<T>>

Tags: java, generics, self-type

It is hard for me to understand the simulated self type idiom

```
abstract class Foo<T extends Foo>
{
    public abstract T doSomething();
}
```

and

```
abstract class Foo<T extends Foo<T>>
{
    public abstract T doSomething();
}
```

In both cases `doSomething()` returns a type which is `Foo` or a sub type of `Foo`

So basically it says that the type parameter of `T` must extend `Foo` or be `Foo`.
Where do I need now the `Foo<T>` or in which cases do I need the second one instead of the first one? What do I am missing out?

I am looking for cases where the first one would not work but the second one would.

Comment: Are you aware of what a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) is? The `Foo` in the first code snippet is a raw type.

Comment: Sure, I know it is a raw type. But still it is a `Foo` and would satisfy the doSomething() method. Honestly, I don't understand the self type idiom.

Comment: @MichaelSchulz then you do not know what a raw type is, because `Foo` is a raw type. In the rawtype, `T` could be a `Foo<SomethingOtherThanT>`, leading to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I know that Foo itself is a Rawtype because it is missing the concrete Type of Foo. Just as rawtype List. Which would allow adding different objects at compile time. Why could it be Foo<SomethingOtherThanT> as T is bound to be a subtype of T

Comment: So the only purpose of the Selfreferencing Type Parameter is to prevent usage raw types?